# Can not write new file in android directory

Tags: android, image, android-intent

i recently have good spirit to develop android application and haved asked so many times about android programming, so don't bother if i asked again :D (Intermezzo)
Actually i got some problem. i have finish develop one application and it worked really fine in my device samsung note 10.1. But when i install the app to other device i got some error and problem
The first one, my application was crashed after i captured image using camera and press button save. i am using intent to open the camera.
The second one, after i'm doing the crop activity, the cropped image can't be write in my own directory but the directory is exist. Here is my code, really glad if you lend me your help :)

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.cobaandroid;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

final int PICTURE_GALLERY = 0;
final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 1;
final int PIC_CROP = 2;
public static final int MEDIA_IMAGE = 3;
private Uri picUri;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tampilkanUserManual();
    Button ambilGambar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ambil_gambar);
    Button gallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ambilGallery);
    ambilGambar.setOnClickListener(this);
    gallery.setOnClickListener(this);
    if(!supportCamera())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Maaf device anda tidak mendukung penggunaan kamera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
    Button exit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exit);
    exit.setOnClickListener(this);
}

//Cek apakah device memiliki kamera
private Boolean supportCamera()
{
    if(getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

// Button onClick 
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(v.getId()==R.id.ambil_gambar)
    {
        try
        {
            //Intent untuk menggunakan kamera
            Intent intentAmbil = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intentAmbil,CAMERA_CAPTURE);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException activity)
        {
            String errorMessage = "ga support kamera";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
    else if(v.getId()==R.id.ambilGallery)
    {
        try
        {
            //intent untuk ngambil gambar di galeri
            Intent ambilGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            ambilGallery.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(ambilGallery, PICTURE_GALLERY);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException activity)
        {
            String errorMessage = "Tidak dapat mengambil gambar dari galeri";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
    else if(v.getId()==R.id.exit)
    {
        try
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException ac)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tidak dapat menutup aplikasi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        if(requestCode==CAMERA_CAPTURE)
        {

            BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            //option.inSampleSize = 8;
            option.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            Bitmap hasilPoto = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            if(hasilPoto==null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "bitmap null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            picUri = data.getData();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), picUri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent cropIntent= new Intent (this, Crop.class);
            cropIntent.putExtra("data", picUri.toString());
            cropIntent.putExtra("gambar", hasilPoto);
            cropIntent.putExtra("kode","kamera");
            startActivity(cropIntent);
        }
        else if(requestCode==PICTURE_GALLERY)
        {
            // Resize gambar dari galeri
            Uri galeriUri = data.getData();
            String[] path = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(galeriUri,path,null,null,null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(path[0]);
            String gambarPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opt.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            opt.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(opt, 50, 100);

            Bitmap hasilPoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(gambarPath);
            //Bitmap hasilPoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(gambarPath, opt);
            hasilPoto = scaleDown(hasilPoto, 100, getApplicationContext());
            Intent cropIntents = new Intent(this,Crop.class);
            cropIntents.putExtra("data", galeriUri.toString());
            cropIntents.putExtra("kode","galeri");
            cropIntents.putExtra("gambar",hasilPoto);
            cropIntents.putExtra("path", gambarPath);
            startActivity(cropIntents);
        }
    }
}
//fungsi untuk scaling gambar
private Bitmap scaleDown(Bitmap photo, int newHeight,Context contex)
{
    final float densityMultiplier = contex.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int h = (int) (newHeight*densityMultiplier);
    int w = (int) (h*photo.getWidth()/(double)photo.getHeight());
    photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, h, true);
    return photo;
}

//tampilkan userManual
private void tampilkanUserManual()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_usermanual, null);
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

}

in MainActivity.java i am work with camera and gallery where the user can pick the image from gallery or captured it with camera.
here is the xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/daun2"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/showTextHome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/showText"
    android:textSize="40sp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Keluar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ambil_gambar"
    android:layout_width="276dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ambilGallery"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/showTextHome"
    android:text="@string/ambil" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ambilGallery"
    android:layout_width="276dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/exit"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ambil_gambar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:text="@string/ambilGall" />
```

And after user pick or captured the image, the intent called next activity Crop.java. in this class the user can crop the image and automatically save it to directory called 'Dataset'

```
package com.example.cobaandroid;
import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Crop extends Activity  {
public static int[] rataRed ;
public static  int[] rataGreen ;
public static  int[] rataBlue ;
final int PIC_CROP = 2;
final int levelBWd = 6;
public static final int MEDIA_IMAGE = 3;
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Dataset";
private Uri fileUri;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crop);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gambarPoto);
    String uriPassed = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
    fileUri = Uri.parse(uriPassed);
    String intentKode = getIntent().getStringExtra("kode");
    if(intentKode.equals("kamera"))
    {
        Bitmap bmp = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("gambar");
        img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        System.out.println("Gambar diambil dari kamera");
    }
    else if(intentKode.equals("galeri"))
    {
        String path = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("path");
        Bitmap bmp = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("gambar");
        img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        System.out.println("Gambar diambil dari galeri");
    }
    Button cropButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cropButton);
    cropButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    int hasCroped = 0;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
            int jumlahFile = cekDirektoriDataSet(dir);
            if(jumlahFile==0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Anda belum melakukan Crop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if(jumlahFile < levelBWd)
            {
                try
                {
                    if(jumlahFile !=0)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Anda sudah melakukan Crop sebanyak "+hasCroped, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    hasCroped++;
                    Intent intentCrop = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                    intentCrop.setDataAndType(fileUri, "image/*");
                    Uri tempUri = fileUri;
                    tempUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_IMAGE);
                    intentCrop.putExtra("crop","true");
                    intentCrop.putExtra("AspectX", 0);
                    intentCrop.putExtra("AspectY", 0);
                    intentCrop.putExtra("outputX", 256);
                    intentCrop.putExtra("outputY", 256);
                    intentCrop.putExtra("return-data",true);    
                    intentCrop.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intentCrop, PIC_CROP);
                }
                catch(ActivityNotFoundException activity)
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tidak dapat melakukan crop melebihi jumlah level warna BWD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }       
    });
    // DataSet ListView dan Hitung RGB
    Button view = (Button)findViewById(R.id.list);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dir.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            int jumlahFile = cekDirektoriDataSet(dir);
            if(jumlahFile > 0)
            {
                Intent listIntent = new Intent(Crop.this,DataSet.class);
                listIntent.putExtra("uri", fileUri.toString());
                Crop.this.startActivity(listIntent);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Tidak ada citra di direktroi Dataset", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });

}
// store gambar (file URI)
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri (int type)
{
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

private File getOutputMediaFile (int type)
{
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
    //buat media file name
    int indexGambar = cekDirektoriDataSet(mediaStorageDir);
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_IMAGE)
    {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + (indexGambar+1)+".jpg");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mediaFile.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    else return null;
    return mediaFile;   
}


public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth,int reqHeight)
{
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;
    if(height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth)
    {
        final int halfHeight = height/2;
        final int halfWidth = width/2;
        while((halfHeight/inSampleSize)>reqHeight && (halfWidth/inSampleSize)>reqWidth)
        {
            inSampleSize*=2;
        }
        long totalPixels = width*height/inSampleSize;
        final long totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth*reqHeight*2;
        while(totalPixels > totalReqPixelsCap)
        {
            inSampleSize*=2;
            totalPixels/=2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}


private Bitmap scaleDown(Bitmap photo, int newHeight,Context contex)
{
    final float densityMultiplier = contex.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int h = (int) (newHeight*densityMultiplier);
    int w = (int) (h*photo.getWidth()/(double)photo.getHeight());
    photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, h, true);
    return photo;
}
//cek jumlah atau isi direktori
private int cekDirektoriDataSet(File dir)
{
    if(!dir.exists())
    {
        if(!dir.mkdir())
        {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Gagal membuat direktori" + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + "direktori");
        }
    }
    File[] listDir = dir.listFiles();
    return listDir.length;
}
```

}

here is the xml for crop

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/daun2"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gambarPoto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/list"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="86dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/gambar"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cropButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gambarPoto"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:text="@string/crop" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/showCrop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/showTextCrop"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cropButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cropButton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gambarPoto"
    android:text="@string/Dataset" />
```

I really need Your help
Big Thanks...

Comment: device used, stacktrace.

Comment: You need to do some debugging - with the debugger.  When you have isolated where the crash is happening and, if you still can't figure out why, ask a more specific question and include the stack trace.

Comment: thanks for your reply, for my first problem, i found that the error is java.lang.Nullpointer at mainactivity.java but for the second one i can't find any :(